# Reusing window in Qt

Tags: qt, user-interface, qml, qtquick2, qt6

I want to create a desktop application using Qt Quick and QML. I understand so far how to manage widgets until I need to change the whole UI.

**Example:** After logging into Telegram, it loads a completely different UI with the list of your chats.

What is a better way to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `StackView` for this.

From the Qt Documentation for `StackView`:

```
 ApplicationWindow {
 title: qsTr("Hello World")
 width: 640
 height: 480
 visible: true

 StackView {
     id: stack
     initialItem: mainView
     anchors.fill: parent
 }

 Component {
     id: mainView

     Row {
         spacing: 10

         Button {
             text: "Push"
             onClicked: stack.push(mainView)
         }
         Button {
             text: "Pop"
             enabled: stack.depth > 1
             onClicked: stack.pop()

         }
         Text {
             text: stack.depth
         }
     }
 }
 }
```

Basically you push and pop `Components` to the stack. You can also activate Components on the stack, so you don't have to create them everytime you need an specific item.